# How to check if an image file exists or not using OGNL?

Tags: java, image, struts2, ognl

I am creating a JSP page and using OGNL I want to check if an image file exists in directory then display it, otherwise display a blank image. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the JSP you could create an OGNL expression in the `s:if` tag and call the method of the action that returns `boolean`.  For example

```
<s:if test="%{isMyFileExists()}">
  <%-- Show the image --%>
</s:if>
<s:else>
  <%-- Show blank image --%>
</s:else>
```

in the action

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

  private File file;
  //getter and setter here


  public boolean isMyFileExists throws Exception {
    if (file == null) 
      throw new IllegalStateException("Property file is null");       
    return file.exists();
  }
}
```

or directly use `file` property if you add public getter and setter to it

```
<s:if test="%{file.exists()}">
  <%-- Show the image --%>
</s:if>
<s:else>
  <%-- Show blank image --%>
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in several ways, but you should perform this kind of business in the Action and read from JSP only the **boolean** result. Or at least declare the File as an Action property, expose it through a Getter and invoke `.exist()` method from OGNL:

in Action

```
private File myFile
// Getter
```

in JSP

```
<s:if test="myFile.exists()">
```

Just for the records, other possible ways (not to be used for this purpose, simply to better explore OGNL capabilities):

1. call a static method from OGNL (you need `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess` set to `true` in `struts.xml`)

   ```
   <s:if test="@my.package.myUtilClass@doesThisfileExist()" />
   ```

   and in myUtilClass

   ```
   public static boolean doesThisFileExist(){
       return new File("someFile.jpg").exists();
   }
   ```
2. or with parameters

   ```
   <s:if test="@my.package.myUtilClass@doesThisFileExist('someFile.jpg')" />
   ```

   and in myUtilClass

   ```
   public static boolean doesThisFileExist(String fileName){
       return new File(fileName).exists();
   }
   ```
3. or by instantiating it in OGNL directly

   ```
   <s:if test="new java.io.File('someFile.jpg').exists()" />
   ```